# How can I return both types of data in an action inside my controller?

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc

So, I have an ActionResult inside my controller that is supposed to grab the existing values from my database and return the parameters to the view.

My method is called ReadMeasurements and it grabs Angle and point data.I want to return both angle and point data if it exists/not null.

I noticed the way I have it set up right now, I am only returning my angle data because when angle data and point data is not null, the code only returns the angle data and not the point data.

How can I return both angle and point data inside my method?

Here's my code:

```
[OutputCache(NoStore = true, Duration = 0, VaryByParam = "*")]
public ActionResult ReadMeasurements([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request, string viewType)
{
    JsonResult json = new JsonResult();
    List<AngleData> angledata = UserSession.GetValue(StateNameEnum.Planning, ScreenName.Planning.ToString() + "Angles" + viewType, UserSessionMode.Database) as List<AngleData>;
    List<PointData> pointData = UserSession.GetValue(StateNameEnum.Planning, ScreenName.Planning.ToString() + "Points" + viewType, UserSessionMode.Database) as List<PointData>;

    if (angledata != null)
    {
        List<PlanningViewParam> angles = new List<PlanningViewParam>();
        foreach (AngleData i in angledata)
        {
            string col = "#" + ColorTranslator.FromHtml(String.Format("#{0:X2}{1:X2}{2:X2}", (int)(i.color.r * 255), (int)(i.color.g * 255), (int)(i.color.b * 255))).Name.Remove(0, 2);
            int angleVal = (int)i.angleValue;
            angles.Add(new PlanningViewParam()
            {
                Color = col,
                Label = "Angle",
                Value = angleVal,
                Number = i.angleNumber
            });
        }
        return json = Json(angles.ToDataSourceResult(request, i => new PlanningViewParam()
        {
            Color = i.Color,
            Label = i.Label,
            Value = i.Value,
            Number = i.Number
        }), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

    }
    if (pointData != null)
    {
        List<PlanningViewParam> points = new List<PlanningViewParam>();
        foreach (PointData f in pointData)
        {
            string col = "#" + ColorTranslator.FromHtml(String.Format("#{0:X2}{1:X2}{2:X2}", (int)(f.color.r * 255), (int)(f.color.g * 255), (int)(f.color.b * 255))).Name.Remove(0, 2);
            string pointAnglesVal = f.pointAnglesValue;
            points.Add(new PlanningViewParam()
            {
                Color = col,
                Label = "Points",
                ValueTwo = pointAnglesVal,
                Number = f.pointNumber
            });
        }
        return json = Json(points.ToDataSourceResult(request, f => new PlanningViewParam()
        {
            Color = f.Color,
            Label = f.Label,
            Value = f.Value,
            Number = f.Number
        }), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

    }

    return null;
}
```

Comment: Make a new composite class with properties e.g. `AngleData Angle {get;set;} PointData Point {get;set;}`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create a type that holds them both and return that instead:

```
public class PointAndAngle
{
    public Point Point { get; set; }
    public Angle Angle { get; set; }
}

var pAndA = new PointAndAngle { Point = p, Angle = a };
return Json(pAndA);
```

You could do it with an anonymous type if you wanted too:

```
return Json(new { Point = p, Angle = a});
```

Comment: Is there another way to do this or this is the only way? EDIT: when I create the class, I would have to add that class to my models?

Comment: no, you wouldn't. you're returning Json, so this class is only used for this.

Comment: So, I would keep my logic data the same but return both point and angle when I'm returning json

Comment: yup. isn't that what you wanted?

Comment: I ended up just returning the two lists like you did below with anonymous type.

Answer (score 2):

ok, if you `return' from a function then, the function ends and you get an output. you need to concate both data types into an object that you can return.

try something like

```
public class data
{
 public AngleData angle {get; set;}
 public PointData point { get; set;}
}
```

Return a object of type `data` in your function.

Comment: Okay, I will return an object but I also have json parameters I want to return. So it should be data object with different parameter results for point and angle?

Comment: As long as they are parameters inside of the objects then you should be fine. Remember granulated programming is easier to debug on the long run, so try to break down your code into smaller chunks.